# Filemaker calculation to display commas properly in a list

Tags: filemaker

I have a list of items that I need to appear in a report if they are tagged.  As you can see by the code below it's nothing more than a list of numbers separated by commas.  The problem is if #1 isn't in the list, then the list is always preceded by a comma.  I can move the commas to the end but then I'll have the same problem after the last number if it's not the last number in my calculation.  Does anyone have any idea how to adjust this so the commas only appear between numbers?  It would be great if I could get a period after the last number as well.

//Spares calc

If ( ${1} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 1 ; "1" ; "" ) &

If ( ${2} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 2 ; ", 2" ; "" ) &

If ( ${3} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 3 ; ", 3" ; "" ) &

If ( ${4} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 4 ; ", 4" ; "" ) &

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `List` function for this, since it excludes empty items.  Just pass your numbers and empty strings as parameters to `List`, and then replace the newlines with commas, and tack a period on the nend.

```
Substitute ( List("1" ; "" ; "3" ; "4") ; "¶" ; ", ") & "."
```

The above results in:

```
1, 3, 4.
```

In your example, you can use Case statements as arguments to List:

```
Substitute ( List(
     Case ( ${1} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 1 ; "1" ) ;
     Case ( ${2} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 2 ; "2" ) ;
     Case ( ${3} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 3 ; "3" ) ;
     Case ( ${4} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 4 ; "4" ) ;
) ; "¶" ; ", ") & "."
```

Comment: Amazing, you just made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going about what you're doing the hard way, but without seeing more of the detail, just change your calc to :

```
If ( ${1} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 1 ; "1, " ; "" ) &

If ( ${2} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 2 ; "2, " ; "" ) &

If ( ${3} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 3 ; "3, " ; "" ) &

If ( ${4} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 4 ; "4, " ; "" )
```

Then after that you can can change the last ", " to a "." but you may need to check how many ( if any ) appear in the final value first.  Use the Let function to put the result into a variable that you can manipulate later.